# Slow to seek for HLS videos?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I use HLS videos with ExoPlayer. Segments are broken down into 6 seconds each. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my implementation of HLS or if it's an issue with [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

My app has a feed of videos (in a `RecyclerView`). I've set it up such that when a video stops, it saves the position in a map and the player gets detached. However, if the user scrolls back up to view that same video, when I call `exoPlayer.seekTo(position)`, it usually takes a second or two for the video to start playing again from the saved position.

What can I do to make sure that the video plays instantly? Would caching each video solve my problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of seconds to start up a video at a position in the middle is actually quite quick.

The player has to get the video header data, find the nearest place it can start decoding the video, e.g. an I frame, and then decode enough frames to start displaying.

One way to achieve something faster than this is to try to predict the videos a use may go to next and have them preloaded in a separate instance of a player. For example, you might have the last and the next video in the series pre-loaded if the user swipes from one video to another.

Comment: Just wondering how Twitter does it since it seems to be almost instantaneous when seeking through their videos. Is caching the video (temporarily) an option as well, as it's downloading?

Comment: I can't comment on Twitter directly but preloading and having at least the start of the video decoded and ready to go is the usual approach.